# ORMLite "join on" select

Tags: android, ormlite

Hi I need this select:

```
SELECT d.* FROM departure d
JOIN trip t
ON d.trips_fk_id = t._id
WHERE t.downloaded == 1
ORDER BY d.departure_date_time;
```

But i have no idea how to do. Ormlite is not support `JOIN ON`. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far or how you build your select statement (excluding the join)?

Comment: I tried a lot of things and i deleted it yet. Now I will try it programmatically by loop.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to do a `LEFT JOIN ON` you can easily move the relations from the `ON` clause to your `WHERE` clause.